# FBReader on android 5.0 cannot read epub

Tags: java, epub

I am a  student,
This is my eclipse Project,on android 4.0 can use,but on android 5.0 have problem.
Epub cannot Import,I don't know what happened.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpAUN.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to provide more information, including any relevant code, and any warnings/errors produced. Please review [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and update your question with more helpful details.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link  tutorial it contains good explanation

```
https://www.epubor.com/how-to-read-drm-epub-on-android-tablet.html
```